# Possible c++11 instance template error on Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

run following code, seems the compiler defined an empty printf();

```
template<typename T>
void printf(T value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    cout << "case 1" << endl;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void printf(T value, Args... args) {
    printf(value);
    cout << "...";
    printf(args...);
    cout << "case 2" << endl;
}
int main() {
    printf(1, 2, "123", 1.1);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using vs 2015 with newest patch. The output is:

```
1
case 1
...2
case 1
...123...1.1
case 1
case 2
case 2
case 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this code, break it down:

1. call `printf(1, 2, "123", 1.1)`
2. call `printf(1)` followed by `...` followed by calling `printf(2, "123", 1.1)`
3. call `printf(2)` followed by `...` followed by calling `printf("123", 1.1)`
4. call `printf("123")` followed by `...` followed by calling `printf(1.1)`
5. *unwinds*, prints `case 2` (from step 4)
6. *unwinds*, prints `case 2` (from step 3)
7. *unwinds*, prints `case 2` (from step 2)

So what makes you think that it's not working?

If you cleaned up your output, it will become self evident..